# Add grid to wpf window using C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to add an array of grids to my WPF window:

```
    Grid[] Tiles = new Grid[20];

    public void LoadTile()
    {

    for (int X = 0; X < Tiles.Length; X++)
    {
        Tiles[X] = new Grid();
        Tiles[X].Height = (TileData[X].SizeY * 90) - 10;
        Tiles[X].Width = (TileData[X].SizeY * 90) - 10;
        Tiles[X].Margin = new Thickness(0 + (TileData[X].PositionX * 90), 216 + (TileData[X].PositionY * 90), 0, 0);
        Tiles[X].HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        Tiles[X].VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center;

        Tiles[X].Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;

        SolidColorBrush Brush1 = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        Brush1.Opacity = 0.2;
        Tiles[X].Background = Brush1;
    }
    }
```

That's what I have.

(BTW: I do have a method calling that one I just didn't include it here)

I added:

```
    Nine_Window.Content = Tiles[X];
```

But it made it so all I could display was one of them, because each time the loop did that piece of code again it overwrote the last one

Comment: How do you want the `Grid` instances to be displayed? What do you want the screen to look like? More than likely, the right way to do this is to put your `Grid` property values into some data container, then bind a collection of those data container objects to an `ItemsControl.ItemsSource` property, and configure the `ItemsControl`'s `ItemTemplate` and `ItemsPanel`. But without more specific information in your question, it's impossible to say exactly how you would do that.

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Display a set of tiles in a window ? Looks like you're doing it wrong...

Comment: It's simple, I want to create a multiple grid controls in an array and add them to my window.

Answer (score 1):

Your usual use for a grid (let's assume 3x3) will look something along the following in the XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

Regarding your problem with setting the Content, You are setting it to a specific tile instead of to the array. But Again, it'll be easy to do from the XAML I believe, and simply initialize it from code if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are actually looking for is row and column definitions of a grid. Add as many as you need by executing:

```
Grid Tile = new Grid()

// create new columns
ColumDefintion columnDefinition = new ColumnDefinition()
columnDefinition.Height = ... // set height here
Tile.ColumnDefinitions.Add(columnDefinition);

// create a row
Tile.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
```

Otherwise your changes will affect the whole grid object.

Answer (score 0):

Well I donot second your approach but if you want to continue with it, do not add your Grids like this

```
Nine_Window.Content = Tiles[X];
```

instead add a stackPanel to NineWindow.Content

```
<Window ....>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel x:Name="myStackPanel"></StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

and then in code behind

```
myStackPanel.Children.Add(Tile[X]);
```

Comment: Close, but Is there something like a Stack Panel that doesn't stack stuff? It lets you put it anywhere?

Comment: well there are lots of layout options you can find them [here](http://www.wpftutorial.net/LayoutProperties.html) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140613/WPF-Tutorial-Layout-Panels-Containers-Layout-Trans)

Comment: or as Watta mentioned u can use canvas

Answer (score 0):

Okay, Muds nearly got my answer but I'm gonna use a Canvas instead of a Stack Panel.
If you didn't get what I meant, it's simple, I wanted to create a multiple grid controls in an array and add them to my window.